# How to get the real identity of a user when selling digital goods?

Tags: payment, fraud-prevention

In my country we have a very peculiar payment system that it is based on ATM machines, we generate a reference that the user will use in a ATM machine to do the payment.

Lately I've had some troubles with some user or users that do the following:

**1 -** The user goes to my website, make an order with inconsistent data(my fault, I don't verify the e-mail) and receive a reference to pay in the ATM machine.

**2 -** The previous user in the point(1) goes to an online classified ads website and post something to sell incredibly cheap (Iphone, $40) when he finds a buyer give the reference to pay in a ATM machine that was generated in my website.

**3 -** The buyer(victim) pays and got no Iphone, but the money enter in my account. I don't send any digital good because the e-mail is not valid

**4 -** The victim goes to the police and find that the reference is from my business. I return the money to the victim.

This event has happened 2 times... now I need to make sure that this not happens again, but the main problem is that I can't change this payment system it is too popular and the goods are digital, unless I implement a system that sends a mail to the client home with a code to validate the account, there is no way I can have totally sure that the customer will not use the reference to pay in the ATM machine to simple play with people on classified ads websites.

So, I need to have more details about the person who makes an order on my website. For now I only have the IP, but it is easy to use some random wifi network or a proxy. What do you think about implementing these measures?

**1 -** Before send the reference to pay in the ATM machine I will validate the e-mail user with a link send to the e-mail.

**2 -** And I will send an SMS to his phone number with a code.

The e-mail verification is my fault I should have done it before. About the phone verification, do you think that this will demotivate similar attacks?

Best Regards

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding something correctly, but that seems like a strange way to mess with you.  The actor in step 1 never receives any money or sends any product, so what's the point of the whole scheme except to be a nuisance to you?  And what does your measure 1 solve?  It's fairly trivial to set up a junk e-mail account, receive link, then move on to step 2 and post the activation on a classified ad.  What does sending the SMS code in measure 2 solve, and when do you send it?

Comment: LittleBobbyTable, yes the attacker does not benefit at all, it is just messing with me and with random people on classified ads websites. The thing with SMS verification is that I will have a number to send to the police, until now I only have IP addresses.

Comment: But what if they have a [burner phone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepaid_mobile_phone) as well?  I know it's unlikely, but if someone wanted to really mess with you, your measures are only a slight nuisance/inconvenience to them.

Comment: off the top of my head: provide a verification service for references that confirm that reference is linked to a product. give them a 'lifetime' by including date time as part of the reference. As has been pointed out this is difficult to prevent as the 'attacker' is just being 'naughty'. It costs them time and effort is all. ;-/

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot control this system outputs (for example, output payment description into ATM so victim could see that it's not iphone), do you offer other payment options except ATM ?

If so, can you offer this ATM links only to the customers with at least 1 successful purchase, and, exclude ATMs for the first one? In this case, fraud will be expensive for attacker, and, he'll be verified by his first purchase. (via credit card, paypal or something else)

Answer (score 0):

i really dont get you but it seems like the root of even the fact youre asking is that you did not validate email?

you should be able to validate it as far as its possible, just put it between your website and the request to generate the link for ATM-payment. You will be able to, even if you had to write a rewrite rules and put it through some proxy, if not, it doesnt seem to be really your website.

if you want good fraud protection let the possible attacker visit you or some staff of yours and let him leave some deposit, or at least do this phone code sms verification.

Comment: so then invite the possible attacker to your friends, or better in lots of countries there are even api´s for matching an id cards number to a set of root-person data like first and last name